# Crystal Report Export to PDF not working

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I'm trying to export Crystal report to PDF format from ASP.NET C#. I want it to be downloaded directly to the client.

When I click on the button, nothing happens.

```
            string parameter = ViewState["strInvoiceID"].ToString();
            TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UID"];
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PWD"];

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("InvoiceReport.rpt");
            rd.Load(reportPath);

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in rd.Database.Tables)
                tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);


            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = parameter;

            rd.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["InvoiceID"].CurrentValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            rd.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["InvoiceID"].ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Invoice" + parameter + ".pdf");
```

Appreciate your help.
Also, Is there any more optimized way for passing parameters to the report?

Comment: Please define "Nothing happens". Does the report run but not export?

Comment: Nothing happens - > When I click on Download button, nothing happens. No report comes/ or gets downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to export it to, try this which will save it to disk:

```
rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "C:\report.pdf");
```

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:

Try setting your asAttachment parameter to false and see what happens:

```
  rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, 
 "Invoice" + parameter + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for the option. I have already tried this and it works. But we would like the report to get downloaded as pdf without saving it on disk.

Comment: When you say "downloaded", what exactly do you mean? Downloading to me means saving something on my hard drive.

Comment: See revised answer please.

Comment: Right, but here since the code(ASP.NET C#) will run on server, it will download the file to server. Hence, I will then have to redirect the user to the path where file was saved on server, in order for him to download it. This is a two step process. I wanted it to get downloaded directly to client browser.

Comment: It works on a new ASP page. But on my existing page with all the controls, it doesn't seem to work. Anyways I achieved what was required thanks for the help.